# Web Test Conditional Flow

Tags: conditional-statements, webtest, load-testing

I have created a webtest which is a series of web service requests. My data source contains a list of mobile numbers and these mobile numbers can be of two types - A and B. The problem is that data source contains the mix of A and B. When the test runs, it loads one mobile number from the data source (XML file). I want to determine when the test is running as to what is the type of the mobile number (A or B)! Because depending on that I will be sending appropriate message to the web server.

It is however possible for me to create a text file which contains key value pairs (mobile number, type) before running the tests. However adding a plugin which reads the whole file and then finds the mobile number type will be too slow. Is it possible to have these mappings stored in memory during the entire duration of the test? So that I can just query them?

Thanks

Amare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the XML file as the data source, use your new text file as the data source.

For example, if your data source is `DataSource1` and your file is `numbers.csv`, and you have columns `mobile number` and `type` then in your test you can refer to the following context parameters:

- `DataSource1.numbers#csv.mobile#number`
- `DataSource1.numbers#csv.type`

Use a pair of String Comparison Conditional Rules to decide which request to execute depending on the value of `DataSource1.numbers#csv.type`.